# Please explain the function of context for observeValueForKeyPath method

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters

Please explain the function of this parameter

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

what is the main purpose of the parameter context

from the developer library the context means

context
The value that was provided when the receiver was registered to receive key-value observation notifications

what kind of value? is it the value of the KeyPath variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is an arbitrary pointer to any object you want. The idea is you may need some reference to some other data or object when the value at the path changes.

From the docs:

> When you register an object as an observer, you can also provide a context pointer. The context pointer is provided to the observer when `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` is invoked. The context pointer can be a C pointer or an object reference. The context pointer can be used as a unique identifier to determine the change that is being observed, or to provide some other data to the observer.